# Transparent Control to be placed of a picturebox

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, picturebox

I have a PNG file that displays crosshairs in a picturebox on my winform.  I have created a user control that contains another small picture box (for a green dot), and a label.

What i want to do is place the user control over the picture box so that only the dot and label are visible. and the square edges of the control are invisible.

The dot has white edges since the png is actually square, so i attempted to set the Transparency key to be white, but when i add the control to my picture box, everything that is white is transparent.

I thought that if i colored around the edge of my dot with a color, then i can match that with the transparency key, but the colors have to be exact (right?), and my only method of painting is in windows paint, so i can't know if have matched the colors.  Any help?

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are running into is that WinForms controls do not support true transparency, and getting them to do so can be a bit tricky.  What they do is paint the child control under themselves (when transparency is enable via SetStyle), but this has its own quirks.  You should first try something like this:

```
// in your custom control class...
protected override CreateParams CreateParams
{
    get
    {
        CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
        cp.ExStyle |= 0x00000020; //WS_EX_TRANSPARENT

        return cp;
    }
}
```

I have found this method to be more reliable than the following, but you should try this as well:

```
public MyTransparentControl()
{
    SetStyle( ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor |     
              ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint |
              ControlStyles.UserPaint, true );

    BackColor = Color.Transparent;
}
```

As an alternative approach, have you considered using WPF instead of WinForms?  I know this is not always an option, but if it is you will make your life a whole lot easier as WPF controls support transparency and control layering out of the box.

Comment: Do i have to worry about the transparency key on the parent dialog?
The first example works a bit better than the second.  The background of the label, and of the picture box in my control are still there.  The rest of the control is invisible.  Can that example be extended to those items?

Comment: @Jason: You don't have to worry about `TransparencyKey` using this method. You'll need to do the same for every control that should have a "transparent" background.  This means deriving your own Label class, etc.  However, it may be sufficient to use the second example for the label (`SetStyle` is a public method) and use the first example for the main overlay control.